# org-tags-view vs. org-agenda, M

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, tags

My goal is a shortcut for an oft-used command.

The oft-used command:
An agenda view of all unfinished tasks matching a given tag:

```
 1. M-x org-agenda
 2. Prompts for the type of agenda
 3. I enter "M"
 4. Prompt appears to enter tag(s) to match
 5. I input the string 'tag1'
 6. I get all the unfinished items that match 'tag1' (success)
```

Is there a way to jump directly to step 4, 5, or 6?  When I try, for example,

```
M-x org-tags-view
```

it defaults to the

```
org-agenda, "m"
```

behavior, which gives me *every* headline with tag1, rather than just unfinished action items.  I see options for creating custom agenda commands, but so far, they all give a list of *all* headlines, not just action items.  I expect I'm making a stupid mistake, but too new to see it.

If it helps, I'm running
Win10
GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, i686-w64-mingw32)

Comment: The easiest way is to customize the variable `org-agenda-custom-commands`:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html  Then, when you type `M-x org-agenda`, your custom search will have a letter or number for you to press ...  That being said, you can create a custom function that calls `org-tags-view`, but I am probably the only crazy person who would do something like that ... you can type `M-x describe-function` aka `C-h f` and look up the mandatory and optional arguments for `org-tags-view`.

Comment: Just create a function `(defun my-org-agenda-M () (interactive) (org-agenda nil "M"))` and then `M-x my-org-agenda-M`.